# How do I fix this corrupted 7zip archieve to recover all of my data?

Tags: data-recovery, compression, 7-zip

I archieved some files in 7zip in parts in Windows 10 and I uploaded that on cloud. I downloaded it on my laptop (Windows 7) and it says archieve is corrupted even when the archieve was working fine on Windows 10 PC. I tried that with another file (7z settings:split into volumes,ultra compressed, solid block size 4GB)  and again downloaded in Windows 7 and again it says corrupted. How do I fix my archieve as I don't have my data on the Windows 10 PC anymore?

Also one thing I would like to say is when I uploaded my files on cloud, the first file had the name like abcd.7z.001 and the second one abcd.7z.002. But when I am downloading it on my laptop, the first file does not retain it's name and changes to just abcd.7z (I already tried adding .001 , it does not help). The file name is correct on the cloud as abcd.7z.001 and and.7z.002 as I had uploaded from Windows 10 PC.

Answer (score 3):

> How do I fix my archive as I don't have my data on the Windows 10 PC anymore?

If you do not have the original data or a copy of the complete archive this isn't possible.  [Parity archives](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parchive) could have been a solution, but it sounds like the data is incomplete, so that isn't possible.

> I would like to say is when I uploaded my files on the cloud, the first file had the name like abcd.7z.001 and the second one abcd.7z.002.

It sounds like you should make file extensions visible.

> The file name is correct on the cloud as abcd.7z.001 and and.7z.002 as I had uploaded from Windows 10 PC.

If it's something like OneDrive or DropBox you might be able to extract the files in the directory.  If it really is due to the file extension being change and not a case of an incomplete archive the problem will be solved using this method.

Comment: So there's no possible way to recover my files?

Comment: Couldn't the header be just corrupted and be fixed?

Comment: If the archive is not complete then your data cannot be recovered.  Parity archives might have helped but those themselves could become corrupt and thus are not even a perfect solution (in addition the software that creates them is considered abandoned).

Comment: My data happens to be on Telegram. I don't think the archieve is wholly corrupted and I think there must be some way to fix the error.